# how I can define the description of url parameters in “mpociot/laravel-apidoc-generator”: “^2.1” package

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

How I can define the description of url parameters?

I want use laravel 5.4 and "mpociot/laravel-apidoc-generator": "^2.1" package.

Just Like shown in image.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `bodyParam` annotation like this:

```php
/**
 * Database authentication
 *
 * @bodyParam email string required Email address.
 * @bodyParam password string required Users password.
 * @param UserAuthenticationRequest $request
 * @return JsonResponse
 * @response JsonResponse
 * @throws AuthenticationException
 */
public function authenticate(UserAuthenticationRequest $request): JsonResponse {
...
}
```

For further information read the [laravel apidoc generator docs](https://laravel-apidoc-generator.readthedocs.io/en/latest/documenting.html)